# BST Deletion c++

Tags: c++

I have a code for deletion of a node in BST. This code shows memory overflows for some values. i cant figure out the problem. isequal() function returns true if both char arrays have same data and compare() functions returns true or false on the basis of values in temp->name and name. It returns true if first argument have bigger values.

```
void delete_data(char *name)
{
    bool found = false;
    tree *temp;
    tree *parent;
    temp=root;


    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(isequal(temp->file_name,name)==true)
        {

            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            parent = temp;
            if(compare(name,temp->file_name)==true)
                temp=temp->right;
            else 
                temp = temp->left;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        cout<<"Data not found"<<endl;
        return;
    }

    if((temp->left==NULL&&temp->right!=NULL)||(temp->left!=NULL&&temp->right==NULL))
    {
        if(temp->left == NULL && temp->right != NULL)
        {
            if(parent->left == temp)
            {
                parent->left = temp->right;
                delete temp;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = temp->right;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(parent->left == temp)
            {
                parent->left = temp->left;
                delete temp;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = temp->left;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    if( temp->left == NULL && temp->right == NULL)
    {
        if(parent->left == temp) parent->left = NULL;
        else parent->right = NULL;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }



    if (temp->left != NULL && temp->right != NULL)
    {
        tree *chkr; 
        if(parent==NULL || parent->left==temp)
        {  
            chkr=temp->right;
            while(chkr->left!=NULL)
                chkr=chkr->left;
            if(parent!=NULL)
                parent->left=temp->right;
            else
                root=temp->right;
            chkr->left=temp->left;
            temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if(parent->right==temp)
        {
            chkr=temp->left;
            while(chkr->right!=NULL)
                chkr=chkr->right;
            parent->right=temp->left;
            chkr->right=temp->right;
            temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
            delete temp;
        }
        return;
    }
```

}

Comment: at a first sight, in `delete_data` fuction, `parent` is uninitialized at the start. if it is found at the first iteration of `while(temp!=NULL)` loop, then parent is pointing to nothing but following lines access to `parent->left` or `parent->right` which is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at it, and it seems that you only initialize parent in the non-trivial case.

If the root is the node that you want to delete, parent is uninitialized. You check if parent is something non-null only in the case where temp has 2 descendants. I would guess that this is the problem.